# Rails 3 & HTML 5 Microdata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

In Rails, is it possible to create a HTML 5 valueless attribute using any of the ActionView Helpers? I'm trying to create the HTML 5 itemprop microdata for google's [BreadCrumbs](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417). Here's the output I'd like to generate:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"></div>
```

But you can see that the **itemscope** attribute value has no value. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this in Rails...

```
content_tag(:div, "somecontent", :itemscope => nil, :item_type => "http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb")
```

... but I can't seem to get generate an attribute without a value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't. [Rails' tag helper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L131) defines a `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper::BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES` array, and any attributes in that array will be outputted as `key=key`, so if you had, say, `tag(:input, :type => :checkbox, :checked => true)`, the output should be `<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' />`.

I presume that this parses properly, since an XML parser is simply going to check for the *presence* of the attribute, so any value should work.

To that end, you could use:

```
content_tag(:div, "somecontent", :itemscope => "itemscope", :item_type ...
```

This will output `itemscope="itemscope"` in the tag, but it should result in the same desired effect when parsed.

Alternately, you could add itemscope to the BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES, then specify `:itemscope => true`.

Comment: Bummer. Great Answer though, Chris. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the result you want if you are willing to override a private Rails method. If you do this, you run the risk of causing problems when upgrading to future versions of Rails that update the private method logic. Since both `<div itemscope ...>` and `<div itemscope="itemscope" ...>` are valid according to the HTML5 spec, making the change below has very little payoff. The only reason I can think of to do this is if you are completely obsessive about your HTML code style.

As Chris Heald said, we will add `itemscope` to `BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES` and then override the tag helper to output boolean attributes without values. (The following tag_options method is modified from Rails/ActionPack 3.0.7 - future readers should copy the contemporary tag_options code and then make the change after the `if BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.include?(key)` line.)

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TagHelper
      BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.merge(['itemscope', :itemscope])
      private
      def tag_options(options, escape = true)
        unless options.blank?
          attrs = []
          options.each_pair do |key, value|
            if BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.include?(key)
              attrs << key.to_s if value
            elsif !value.nil?
              final_value = value.is_a?(Array) ? value.join(" ") : value
              final_value = html_escape(final_value) if escape
              attrs << %(#{key}="#{final_value}")
            end
          end
          " #{attrs.sort * ' '}".html_safe unless attrs.empty?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can now update your view with:

```
content_tag(:div, "somecontent", :itemscope => true, :item_type => "http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"
```

FWIW, I store extensions to existing classes in e.g. `lib/extensions/action_view.rb`; these extensions are loaded by `config/initializers/extensions.rb` which consists of:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'extensions', '*.rb')].each {|f| require f}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the code legwork for an approach this problem. Nice work!