# How to add HTML5 auto focus to a rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, autofocus

I have a text field

```
  = text_field_tag('search_text_1', params[:search_text],
    options = {:type => 'search'} )
```

which generates

```
<input id="search_text" name="search_text_1" type="search">
```

that I want to add HTML5 autofocus to, as in

```
  = text_field_tag('search_text_1', params[:search_text], 
    options = {:type => 'search', :autofocus => true} )
```

This generates

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="search_text" name="search_text_1" type="search">
```

which does actually work, but how I can I get the actual HTML output for the `autofocus` to be as the HTML spec shows, i.e.

```
<input autofocus id="search_text" name="search_text_1" type="search" autofocus>
# Not sure where it goes or if that matters
```

Using

```
options = {:type => 'search', :autofocus }
```

gives

```
.../_search.html.haml:2: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => 
...:type => 'search', :autofocus } )
```

As the HTML5 spec at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input says, "which is a Boolean"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 & HTML 5 Microdata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867404/rails-3-html-5-microdata)

Comment: But I guess you could [use haml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244052/empty-attribute-with-ruby-haml)...

Comment: Either way, [it's valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with

```
= text_field_tag('search_text_1', 
  params[:search_text], 
  options = {:type => 'search', :autofocus => true })
```

and accepting the output of `autofocus='autofocus'`

Answer (score 3):

If you’re willing to patch a private Rails method you can achieve the output you want. Rails writes out boolean attributes with the [`boolean_tag_option` method in the `TagHelper` module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.6/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L165-L167) which produces the `autofocus='autofocus'` format.

If you add the following to an initializer you can replace this method with one that writes out the attribute in the minimized format.

```
module ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  private def boolean_tag_option(key)
    key
  end
end
```

Obviously you need to be careful when upgrading the version of Rails your app is using. This method seems fairly stable at the moment, it is still there in [4.2.0.beta.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0.beta1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L172-L174) and [master](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L174-L176).