# need to generate a very specific html from erb to get the javascript to work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

Im using [this](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) to make a gallery of images in my rails page. The html to put the images is this

```
<a href="assets/gallery/ave.jpg" title="Ave" data-gallery>
  <img src="assets/gallery/ave_tb.jpg" alt="Ave">
</a>
```

im trying to make the code with erb but cant generate the 'data-gallery' part that is necessary to the javascript to work. thanks.

Comment: so far I have this 

    <%= link_to( image_tag("gallery/ave_b.jpg"), image_path("gallery/ave.jpg",)) %>

Comment: This answer may help you: [Rails - link_to helper with data-* attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734722/rails-link-to-helper-with-data-attribute)

Comment: or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26049331/525478)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend end with this solution:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("gallery/chiva_tb.jpg", alt: "Chiva"), 
    image_path("gallery/chiva.jpg"), title: "Chiva", data: {gallery: nil}) %>
```